# Timer in Android not updating

Tags: android, countdown, countdowntimer

I have a timer in android to countdown to a future date, but it is not refreshing. Any help appreciated. my code is posted below:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countdown);

    t.setText(timeDif());
```

I believe that t.setText just needs to be constantly updated, but am unsure of how to do that.

```
}

public String timeDif()
{

   GregorianCalendar then = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 07, 21, 6, 0, 0);
   Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(); 

  long arriveMilli = then.getTimeInMillis();
  long nowMilli = now.getTimeInMillis(); 
  long diff = arriveMilli - nowMilli; 


  int seconds = (int) (diff  / 1000);
  int minutes = seconds / 60; 
  seconds %= 60; 
  int hours = minutes / 60; 
  minutes %= 60; 
  int days = hours / 24; 
  hours %= 24; 

  String time = days + ":" +zero(hours)+":"+zero(minutes)+":"+zero(seconds);

  return time;
}

private int zero(int hours) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


}
```

Comment: I guess right now it's just a string generated from the difference between calendars.  I've done numerous google searches related to this and just cannot figure it out.

Comment: Where is your timer? post the codes.

Comment: Oh. Well, there's SimpleCountdownTimer (IIRC) or a runnable. There are examples of both on the Android site.

Comment: You want to add a timer event (can be done in activity, or in a widget) that updates the string based on the difference between the dates...

Answer (score 1):

The textbox wont update unless you do it in its own thread. The Timer runs on a different thread than the UI. Here is how I did it.

```
myTimer = new Timer();
myTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
   TimerMethod();
                    }
};
myTimer.schedule(myTimerTask, 0, 100);

private void TimerMethod()
{
    //This method is called directly by the timer
    //and runs in the same thread as the timer.
    //We call the method that will work with the UI
    //through the runOnUiThread method.
    if (isPaused != true) {
        this.tmrMilliSeconds--;
        this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
    }
}

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    //This method runs in the same thread as the UI.               
        if (tmrSeconds > 0) {
            if (tmrMilliSeconds <= 0) {
                tmrSeconds--;
                tmrMilliSeconds = 9;
            }
        } else {
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(1000);
            myTimer.cancel();
            tmrSeconds = setTime;
            tmrMilliSeconds = 0;
            isPaused = true;
        }

    //Do something to the UI thread here
        timerText.setText(String.format("%03d.%d", tmrSeconds, tmrMilliSeconds));
    }
};
```

That is part of the code for a count down clock I made for an ap. It demonstrates how to have one thread run (The public void run()) part, and then another part that runs on the UI thread. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing this with a timer.  A timer uses a thread and you don't need one (and it complicates things unnecessarily).  You need to use a Runable and Handler's postDelayed method to do it.  It is easier and lighter weight.

```
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
             //update here 
             mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
       }
    };

    private void startTimer()
    {
         mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
         mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }
```